# How to vertically centre a multicolumn inside a longtable environment?

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable, multicolumn, longtabu

I've got a merged column inside a table using `multicolumn`. I would like the text in this multicolumn to be centered vertically. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm, top=3.17cm, bottom=3.17cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu,longtable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|p{0.1\textwidth}|X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{1.} & stuff \\ \hline
        \textbf{2.} & stuff \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\large{\textbf{Reports}}} \\[3ex] \hline
    \end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

I've tried various combinations of things including defining a column type using:

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

and:

```
\usepackage{array}
\multicolumn{2}{|M{1cm}|}{\large{\textbf{Reports}}} \\[3ex] \hline
```

But this does not work. I've seen lots of examples using `tabular` but I need my table to span multiple pages.

Comment: tabu is buggy and unmaintained. See the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/. I no longer try to answer questions using tabu. So consider if you really want to use it.

Comment: I've used `tabu` as I couldn't find a way to make `longtable` scale to textwidth easily and automatically scale the width of the last column accordingly.

Comment: You could try https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular. But I normally simply calculate the width. In your example eg. the second column could use `p{\dimexpr 0.9\textwidth-4\tabcolsep -3\arrayrulewidth}` (but I would use less rules ...)

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package: vertical centering is easy inside `longtblr` environemnt.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm, top=3.17cm, bottom=3.17cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Title},
  label = {tblr:test},
]{
  colspec = {|t{0.1\textwidth}|X|},
  column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  row{3} = {3em},
  cell{3}{1} = {c=2}{m,font=\large\bfseries}, % multicolumn
  hlines,
}
  1.      & stuff \\
  2.      & stuff \\
  Reports &       \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see a more general solution, but this worked for me:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm, top=3.17cm, bottom=3.17cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu,longtable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|p{0.1\textwidth}|X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{1.} & stuff \\ \hline
        \textbf{2.} & stuff \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|} \\[1ex]
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\large{\textbf{Reports}}} \\[3ex] \hline
    \end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

I've added an empty row scaled to the right size above the row whose height I changed.